# При выдаче JSON кириллица не выдается

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring

Всем привет!
Я поставил сервер java + spring на VPS Ubuntu, запустил, полёт нормальный, но когда пытаюсь выдать JSON с сервера по ссылке http://139.59.164.239:8080/menuserver/dishes выходит JSON но без кириллицы, кириллица заменяется на непонятные символы.База у меня postgresql, там есть некоторые записи на кириллице. Я этот JSON буду парсить и ложить в андроид, в листвью. Как мне нормально выдавать JSON?

JSON выдается сейчас в таком виде:

> [{"id":1,"title_ru":"Р§РёР·РєРµР№Рє","title_eng":"CheeseCake","description_ru":"Р‘СѓС‚РµСЂР±СЂРѕРґ
>   СЃ СЃС‹СЂРѕРј","description_eng":"Brad with
>   cheese","url":"www.artlabteam.com","img_url":"www.artlabteam.com/pic1.jpg","weight":1,"category_id":2,"status":1},{"id":2,"title_ru":"РҐРѕС‚-РґРѕРі","title_eng":"Hotdog","description_ru":"Р‘СѓС‚РµСЂР±СЂРѕРґ
>   СЃ РіРѕСЂСЏС‡РµР№ СЃРѕСЃРёСЃРєРѕР№","description_eng":"Brad with
>   sosage","url":"www.artlabteam.com","img_url":"www.artlabteam.com/pic2.jpg","weight":1,"category_id":2,"status":1}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было поставить фильтры кодирования символов в java config:

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```

Делал по этой статье: http://javastudy.ru/spring-mvc/java-config-web-xml/

Answer (score 3):

Посмотри на настройки [Locale](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_ubuntu), Русификация Ubuntu

```
sudo update-locale LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Comment: буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: у меня теперь tomcat упал и не запускается :( ошибок не выдает, но по ссылке tomcat недоступен

Comment: Перезапусти и смотри на логи.

Comment: в каких логах именно? я подключаюсь к впс через putty по ssh, в логах всё ок , вот скрин - http://joxi.ru/5md0VDnIkl8Ddm

Comment: tomcat сам по себе заработал, видимо проблемы были какие-то с VPS, но я после этого ребутнул, запустил его заново, но кириллицу все равно не выдает

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов может тебе сюда, если код пишешь http://yan.zlobin.name/86 и вот еще http://jiffie.blogspot.ru/2012/11/localized-javascript-resources-based-on.html

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать!